# Want to connect to local database from java application on server

Tags: database-connection

I have a local Ms access database in a local computer connected with internet with dynamic IP. And I have a java web application running on web server. How can I connect to Database in local pc with dynamic ip from the java application running on server

Answer (score 0):

You would have to serve it from the client machine using either a local web server or a VPN tunnel.

Possibly a better idea (I mean, anything sounds better than connecting to a client-side DB, right?) would be to have the client upload the database (depending on the size) and then connecting to the server-side copy.